# What are the exact dynamics of the output file sizes of pickle dumps in Python?

Tags: python, pickle

How can I determine the size of the output of a pickle dump before actually dumping it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pickle.dumps()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) to store the dump in a string in memory and check its size.

I don't think there is a simple way to determine this size accurately without invoking the pickle process.